# Refactor code java

Tags: java, refactoring

I have the below piece of code and statements 2(scopeId) and 3(productScopeId) are repetiting in many methods. How can I refactor the below methos in such a way that it can be used in many methods. I don't want to create a class with these two variables and return scope and product scope id. Can you please suggest any other better way. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public List<Product> getAllHydroProducts() 
            throws RepositoryException {
            String productTypeId = getProductTypeId(Group.GROUP_TYPE_NAME_HYDRO, getAllProductTypes());
            String scopeId = getScopeTypeId(Group.SCOPE_TYPE_NAME_HTX, getAvailableScopes());
            String productScopeId = getScopeTypeId(Group.SCOPE_TYPE_NAME_PROJECT, getAvailableScopes());

            return getProductsByTypeAndScope(productTypeId , scopeId ,productScopeId );
        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean 'refactor the below methods in such a way that it can be used in many methods'? There is  one method in your post that calls other methods. It's already one method that can be used by (and uses) other methods.

Comment: Statements scopeId and productScope Id are repetitive in other methods that I am using.

Comment: Well, we can't see the rest of your code, so we can't tell you how to refactor it. You could do all manner of things to change how your code works, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work under the assumption that you have several constants like `Group.GROUP_TYPE_NAME_HYDRO`, and all your methods are just like the one you show us, but with different constants (I believe you should add those other methods to your question, since without them there is no visible repeated code).

You have two possible scenarios (again, with more code would be easier):

1) You are only changing the product type constant, keeping the other two all the same in your other methods. If that's the case, you can just extract a more generic method like:

```
public List<Product> getAllProductsOfType(YourConstantType productType) throws RepositoryException {
        return getProductsByTypeAndScope( 
            getProductTypeId(productType, getAllProductTypes()), 
            getScopeTypeId(Group.SCOPE_TYPE_NAME_HTX, getAvailableScopes()) ,
            getScopeTypeId(Group.SCOPE_TYPE_NAME_PROJECT, getAvailableScopes()) 
        );
}
```

Note that I don't know what your constants are, since you did't put them on your question, that's why `YourConstantType` is there.
Then your existing methods would just call this new one with their parameter.

2) Another scenario: You also have different scopes on your methods. In this case, I might go with a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Also... is that a checked exception what I see there? I hope not ...